# Google test, how to use template in test code, to check types

Tags: c++, unit-testing, templates, googletest

I am trying to write a unit test case for the below function.

```
SQLSMALLINT type_conversion_fn(InputType xtype) {
    switch (xtype) {
    case XSQL_String:        
        return SQL_TINYINT;

    default:
        return SQL_WVARCHAR;
    }
}
```

So my google test file:

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "blabla.hh"

InputType xsql_type;

TEST(xsql, test_type_conversion_fn) {
    SQLSMALLINT result;
    inputType = XSQL_String;
    result = type_conversion_fn(inputType);
    EXPECT_TRUE(::testing::StaticAssertTypeEq<SQL_WVARCHAR, result>());

}
```

I am getting too many errors... The template function is in the documentation
https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#type-assertions

I think for the unit testing, I need to check for the return type matches? So I looked for assert type, and reached the google documentation link. But I do not know how to apply it to my code... Please help. Thank you.

Comment: I think maybe result is a runtime object and you use it in compile time for template parameter.

Comment: @RonTang : Could you be more specific on what I should do please?

Comment: Using runtime assert meet your need?If not,look at SQL_TINYINT and SQL_WVARCHAR ,they have the same type of SQLSMALLINT,we can't distinguish their type.But we can distinguish value at runtime.